# How to convert youtube links in php

Tags: php, string

I want to convert youtube link like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAy5uo4TOAo to 
http://www.youtube.com/v/eAy5uo4TOAo. Can you help me to write a PHP function for this purpose?

Comment: help you write - yes. so what have you got so far?

Comment: @Dagon: when someone says they are "newbie here" it automatically means you have to provide a polished and glossy solution in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming good faith, please look at the functionality of the [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function in PHP.  And here is a simple function I created based on it:

```
function youtube_url_magic_thingamadoo ($url, $scheme = null) {

  $url_parts = parse_url($url);
  $url_parts['scheme'];
  $url_parts['host'];

  $param_parts = explode('=', $url_parts['query']);
  $scheme = !empty($scheme) ? $scheme : $url_parts['scheme'];

  return $scheme . '://' . $url_parts['host'] . '/' . implode('/', $param_parts);

} // youtube_url_magic_thingamadoo
```

And here is how you would call it:

```
$source_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAy5uo4TOAo";
echo youtube_url_magic_thingamadoo($source_url, 'http');
```

And here is the output:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/eAy5uo4TOAo
```

Note I added a `$scheme` parameter to the `youtube_url_magic_thingamadoo()` interface to allow you to override the original URL scheme of `https`.

Answer (score 2):

There you go ducky, now run along and play

```
<?php
$url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAy5uo4TOAo";

$glossy=parse_url($url);
//print_r($glossy);

parse_str($glossy['query'],$polished);

//print_r($polished);

$i_work_for_free=$glossy['scheme'].'://'.$glossy['host'].'/'.key($polished).'/'.$polished[key($polished)];

echo $i_work_for_free;
```

p.s.: yes this is deliberately bloated.